# How to get a separate word out of an object key value?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, key-value

I need to get a `firstName` out of the `fullName`.

How do I do that?

```js
const users = [
  ...,
  {
    firstName: undefined,
    lastName: 'Holy',
    fullName: 'Jack Holy',
  },
  ...,
];
restoreNames(users)
// users === [..., {firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Holy', fullName: 'Jack Holy'}, ...]
```

Comment: fullName.split(' ')[0]

Comment: function restoreNames(users) {

users.firstName = users.fullName.split(' ')[0];

}

returns an error: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
/restoreNames.js:16:34)

Comment: @YuriiParfinenko `users` is an array, you need to index a specific object within it: `users[0].firstName = users[0].fullName.split(' ')[0];`, if you want to do this for all objects, you can use a loop

Comment: @NickParsons so hard, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```js
function restoreNames(users) {
  return users.map((user) => {
    return {
      firstName: user.firstName ? user.firstName : user.fullName.split(" ")[0],
      lastName: user.lastName ? user.lastName : user.fullName.split(" ")[1],
      fullName: user.fullName
        ? user.fullName
        : `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: I created the function to make other cases eg lastName does not exist or fullName